# How to skip items in GroupedListView.builder

Tags: flutter, gridview

I am using `GroupedListView.builder` to build chat messages. I am trying to show multiple images sent by the same user one after the other in the same message. First I detected if at least 4 images is sent by the same user while building a message; then, getting the URLs of those images and show them using `GridView.builder`:

```
GridView.builder(
    itemCount: groupedImages.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ImagePreview(
        imageUrl: groupedImages[index].url!,
        sender: sender,
        isMe: sender == groupedImages[index].sender,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        id: groupedImages[index].id,
        date: date,
      );
    },
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
    ),
  ),
............

void getAllConsecutiveImages() {
for (var element in messages) {
  if (element.type.toLowerCase().contains('image') &&
      element.sender == sender) {
    groupedImages.add(element);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

}

My problem is that I need to delete or skip the images I already got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple solution to do this.

You can maintain a list within your state which is reduced and only contains one example of every image and then make the builder around this list.

```dart
final List<Image> groupedImageReduced = groupedImage.where((element){
  // 'alreadyDisplayed' must be true when 2 images are the same
  if(alreadyDisplayed){
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
});
```

this way you will have a list with only the element that you want.

Otherwise, you can just skip the cases that you want in your builder by returning a Container when the image is already displayed but that is more dirty than the first solution

```dart
GridView.builder(
    itemCount: groupedImages.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if(alreadyDisplayed){
        return Container();
      }else{
        return ImagePreview(
          imageUrl: groupedImages[index].url!,
          sender: sender,
          isMe: sender == groupedImages[index].sender,
          width: width,
          height: height,
          id: groupedImages[index].id,
          date: date,
        );
      }
    },
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
    ),
  ),
```